# US visa is under administrative processing, I need the passport back ASAP

Tags: visas, usa, passports, application-status, us-visa

I have applied for non-immigrant US visa in a foreign country, but my visa processing is delayed and its under "administrative processing". I have my flight back to my home country and I cannot leave the country without my passport. What are my options here? From my understanding (1) I can try to wait it out until I do get my passport back and then go back home. (2) Is there a way I can refuse the visa and just ask for my passport back and how bad will it look on my future visa applications to the US?

Again, from my understanding, this is not exactly 221(g), since its not a direct refusal, so I won't have to bring it up when asked "have you been declined US visa before?" in my future applications. However, I'm assuming this failed application will stay in the system, so will it look bad at all or will it have no effect on future applications?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Contact the consulate immediately and request that your passport be returned. The letter you got when your application was put into administrative processing should have the correct contact information. Otherwise check the US embassy website for your country for contact information. You also could have (and possibly should have) requested it to be returned at your interview.

This does not necessarily cause your application to fail. When administrative processing is complete, [the consulate will contact you](https://jp.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/adminprocessing_statuscheck/) to resubmit your passport to receive the visa (if you are approved).

You can [check your visa application status in CEAC](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx?App=NIV).