# B2 Visa stuck in administrative processing for over 120 days now

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My parents applied for B2 visa in February and were granted visa at the interview at Chennai consulate. My dad got his passport back in 2 days with the visa. My mom received a questionnaire on February 13th and we responded on February 14th, 2019. Usually, when you respond to USCIS you get a confirmation that they received your email/response. But for the questionnaire we din’t get anything. I wrote to “support-india@ustraveldocs.com” twice, once when 60 days had passed and another at 90 days. We always get a generic response saying it’s still under processing and needful is being done. It is unsettling as there is nothing to do but wait. When is the right time to consider withdrawing?
I also need to apply for my parent’s Canada visitor visa but with my mom’s passport stuck indefinitely I don’t know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: You don't need to withdraw the visa application. See [US visa is under administrative processing, I need the passport back ASAP](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137434/3221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the circumstances, Administrative Processing can take anywhere from a few days to 6 months or more, especially if the person is found ineligible to enter the US and requires a waiver of ineligibility to be applied for.

There is very little that you can do during this period other than what you've already done - the only contact allowed is with CGI Federal (aka ustraveldocs.com) who are the company that are contracted by the US Government to provide such services.  However, if you have not already, you should be requesting CGI Federal get an update on the status from the consulate.  If you don't do this they will likely just be looking at the tracking system which will show the current status of the application.  If you instead ask them to contact the consulate they may actually follow-up to find out the current status.

Generally if it was expected that administrative processing was going to take more than a few days then the applicant would have been given their passport back.  It appears that hasn't happened here, however you can contact CGI Federal and state that you require the passport to be returned to your mother and they will arrange for this to occur.  If/when the visa is approved, they will contact her again and she will need to send the passport back to them in order to get the visa "stamped" in it.  Doing this will have the added benefit of requiring CGI Federal to reach out to the consulate, which might help move the process along if it has somehow slipped between the cracks...

Comment: Thank you for the response. Her visa was approved end of July.